# Problems on Kubuntu machine connecting to some sites after AT&T uverse upgrade

Tags: networking, firefox, kubuntu, video, dns

I recently had the U-verse service upgraded, and noticed that Facebook and youtube, and sometimes Yahoo have problems loading and displaying content. I am running Kubuntu 14.04 LTS, and using the latest Firefox.

This doesn't seem  to affect my Fedora computer, or my Win7 machine. Both of which use the latest Firefox with the same config and add ons.

Youtube seems to not want to load videos unless I refresh multiple times, and Facebook doesnt load all the pictures.

I have set my DNS to Google's public DNS, both IPV4 and IPv6, and it's a little better, FB seems to load all the pics now, but Youtube is slow and still can take multiple refreshes to load a video. I can ping both sites with no lost packets, and speedtest.net as well as pingtest.net show good speed and connection. I am still having trouble opening emails in yahoo as well.

None of these problems happen on Win7 and as I said earlier, I'm using the same browser with the same addons/settings on both, and my Android devices work fine, which leads me to believe it's a setting on this Kubuntu machine that I need to change. All other sites seem to work fine, including other streaming video sites.

Comment: Ok, would REALLY like some help on this, I'm still somewhat new to Linux (we were all there at one point) 
Tried chromium, thinking it might be firefox, and the results were even worse, half the time things refused to download and pages didn't load right., leading me to believe it's with Kubuntu somewhere. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out, had to do with IPv6 on the router, no clue why the windows machine didn't have the problem. Turned IPv6 off and everything's fine. 
Each router is different, so the best bet would be to consult the documentation or search the web to figure out how to turn ipv6 off on yours.